# Any way to programatically distinguish between final-param array and final-param ellipsis?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, javadoc, ellipsis

I'm writing some code to create JavaDoc links based on its `java.lang.reflect.Method` or `Constructor` objects. I don't understand how `javadoc.exe` knows the difference between functions that have a final array parameter

```
public static final void doSomething(boolean b, int[] ai, String[] as)  {
}
```

and ones that have an ellipsis parameter

```
public static final void doSomethingElse(String... as)  {
}
```

Given there's no "ellipsis" indication in a class object. It's either [an array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray%28%29) or not an array. The [name of a class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) also includes this indication, via its `[` prefix, but again, only "array-or-not-array", there's no information about ellipses.

Last-param-arrays must have a JavaDoc link ending with `[])`, and last-param-ellipsis links must end with `...)`. Is there any way to programatically distinguish between this?

```
   import  java.lang.reflect.Method;
public class Test  {
  public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
     Method m = null;
     try  {
        m = Test.class.getDeclaredMethod("doSomething", boolean.class, 
           int[].class, String[].class);
     }  catch(Exception x)  {
        throw  new RuntimeException(x);
     }
     System.out.println(m);
  }
  public static final void doSomething(boolean b, int[] ai, String... as)  {
  }
}
```

Output:

```
public static final void Test.doSomething(boolean,int[],java.lang.String[])
```

Comment: Perhaps this is silly, but can you try instantiating both possible signatures programmatically? If they both compile, its `...`, else its just `[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can call `Method.isVarargs();`. Obviously the varargs may appear only at the end of parameter list, so if last element of `method.getParameterTypes()` is array call `Method.isVarargs()`.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I was stuck on the term "ellipsis".